# Selenium web driver scraper

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

i posted question same question due to not able to post it properly i am again posting my question, i have created a scraper using selenium for the website https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/searchlist/searchlist

whenever i run this it goes through every drop down and when it finds useful data to be scraped in csv it gives certain error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\maharera\Maha_Rera.py", line 66, in 
<module>
    selectVillage.select_by_index(villageElement)
  File 
"C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 103, in select_by_index
raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with index %d" % 
index)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate 
element with index 33
```

Below are my codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


import os
import time
import csv
import sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")

driver.get('https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/searchlist/searchlist')

# try:
#     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
#         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Promoter"))
#     )
# finally:
#     print('0000000000000000000000')
#     driver.quit()

time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('Promoter').click()

divisionLength = len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Division')).options)
print('*********{}'.format(divisionLength))

firstRow = 0
titleRow = []
contentRows = []

    for divisionElement in range(1,divisionLength):
    selectDivision = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Division'))
    selectDivision.options
selectDivision.select_by_index(divisionElement)
time.sleep(1)
districtLength = len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District')).options)
while districtLength == 1:
    pass
print(districtLength)
for districtElement in range(1,districtLength):
    selectDistrict = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District'))
    selectDistrict.options

    selectDistrict.select_by_index(districtElement)

    time.sleep(1)

    talukaLength = len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Taluka')).options)
    print('/-----taluka numbers: {}-------/'.format(talukaLength))
    for talukaElement in range(1, talukaLength):
        selectTaluka = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Taluka'))
        selectTaluka.options
        selectTaluka.select_by_index(talukaElement)
        time.sleep(1)

        villageLength = len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Village')).options)
        print('/-----village numbers: {}-------/'.format(talukaLength))
        for villageElement in range(1, villageLength):
            selectVillage = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Village'))
            selectVillage.options
            selectVillage.select_by_index(villageElement)
            time.sleep(2)
            projectLength = len(Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Project')).options)

            print('/------------------------------/')
            print('/-----project number: {}-------/'.format(projectLength))
            print('/------------------------------/')
            if projectLength == 1:
                continue

            for projectElement in range(1,projectLength):
                selectProject = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Project'))
                selectProject.options

                while len(selectProject.options) == 1:
                    pass
                # c = len(select.options)
                # print('---------------{}'.format(c))

                # titleRow = []
                # contentRows = []
                # firstRow = 0

                # for i in range(1,c):
                #     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Project'))
                #     while len(select.options) == 1:
                #         pass
                time.sleep(1)
                selectProject.select_by_index(projectElement)

                driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()
                tableRows = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

                if firstRow == 0:
                    headRow = tableRows[0].find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
                    for headRowData in range(0,len(headRow)):
                        text = headRow[headRowData].find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
                        titleRow.append(text)
                    firstRow = firstRow + 1

                for dataRowsNumbers in range(1,len(tableRows)):
                    dataRow = tableRows[dataRowsNumbers].find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                    tempList = []
                    for dataRowContents in range(0,len(dataRow)):
                        try:
                            a_link = dataRow[dataRowContents].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                            tempList.append(str(a_link))
                        except:
                            tempList.append(str(dataRow[dataRowContents].text))
                        # if dataRow[dataRowContents].text == 'View':
                        #     a_link = dataRow[dataRowContents].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                        #     tempList.append(str(a_link))
                        # else:
                        #     tempList.append(str(dataRow[dataRowContents].text))
                        print(dataRow[dataRowContents].text)
                    print(tempList)
                    contentRows.append(tempList)
# print('Automated check is over')
# print('Stored data in programs is as below:')
# print(contentRows)
if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
    with open("./data.csv",'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvfile.writerow(titleRow)
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0,len(contentRows)):
        csvfile.writerow(contentRows[i])
else:
    with open("./data.csv",'w',newline='') as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        csvfile.writerow(titleRow)
        csvfile.writerow("")
        for i in range(0,len(contentRows)):
        csvfile.writerow(contentRows[i])
driver.close()
```

If someone can please tell, where i doing wrong? i am using python 3.6
i have closed the previous question
i had to give 4 spaces here , but in originals are good written except the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error pops up on line:

```
selectVillage.select_by_index(villageElement)
```

According to the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#selectByIndex-int-):

> This is done by examining the "index" attribute of an element, and not merely by counting.

Therefore, you need to change the code to iterate through the elements themselves rather that `range(1,projectLength)`.

Update:

According to [this](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/03/how-to-select-option-by-value-or-by.html), the solution might be as simple as starting your range from 0 instead of 1:

```
for villageElement in range(0, villageLength - 1):
```

Note: If this works, then you'll need to change the other loops accordingly.

Comment: is there any more help i can expect? if you can help me to modify that code, since i am totally confused